# How to add input fields to a form dynamically with custom validator?

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form with a few integer fields dynamically added in a view, those fields are for the user to rank from 1-N. I've had trouble figuring out how to write a validator that can ensure reach field.data has a unique value and are from from 1 to N.

I've figured out how to dynamically add fields to a form per [wtforms' docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition), but I'd like to validate them all against each other like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815067/how-do-i-validate-wtforms-fields-against-one-another) and I haven't figured out how to properly reference the dynamic fields in the overridden `validate` function.

How can I reference the dynamic fields in my form instance in my validator? In the question linked above they do it in the line:

```
for field in [self.select1, self.select2, self.select3]:
```

But since I'm adding those fields dynamically with `setattr` I don't know those field names. I tried adding a list variable to the Form and appending to that list when I add the dynamic fields but they show up as:

```
<UnboundField(IntegerField, ('first',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.DataRequired object at 0x7ff75a6d7390>]})>
```

Instead of just IntegerFields if I reference a field like `select1` in the example above:

```
<wtforms.fields.core.IntegerField object at 0x7fac1bd54910>
```

How can I reference and validate together these integer fields that I add to my form dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out digging a little closer in the [WTForms documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#field-enclosures), I should have been using a FieldList. And even better than that I can use a FieldList to enclose a list of FieldForms, this provides some more flexibility for adding fields dynamically.