# In WTForms, how do I make optionally required field if another one is empty?

Tags: forms, validation, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have two fields where user can choose one to enter but they can't enter both and they can't skip both either. `Requiered()` makes it that they can't skip one and `Optional()` let them skip both.

I can only find an example for when you want another to be mandatory when you fill one field but I don't know how to modify it to my case because the example inherits a `Required()` validator which makes the two fields both required.

Following is the example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms). Does anybody know if there's a native way to do what I described now or know how to modify this to suit my case?

```
class RequiredIf(Required):
    # a validator which makes a field required if
    # another field is set and has a truthy value

    def __init__(self, other_field_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        super(RequiredIf, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form._fields.get(self.other_field_name)
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.other_field_name)
        if bool(other_field.data):
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I validate wtforms fields against one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815067/how-do-i-validate-wtforms-fields-against-one-another)